# Custom payment method not visible in checkout

Tags: magento2, payment-methods, payment

I have a [magento 2.4.5-p1](https://hub.docker.com/layers/bitnami/magento/2.4.5-p1/images/sha256-dfdf5176cde274e68752e48e4344ffec0a702b8bb4091174c594380392a91444?context=explore) installed. I am trying to install a [custom payment module](https://magento.pavolrasev.com/payment_module.zip), but I don't see it in checkout. (I updated the namespaces to make it work in admin). I went through StackOverflow and tried to google but was not successful in solving the issue. I am a newbie in Magento and this is my first module. I tried to run all `setup:upgrade`, `setup:di:compile`, `cache:clean`, `cache:flush` and `setup:static-content:deploy` but I am not able to make my module appear. I even can't see any error message in the logs. How can I debug why my module is not showing? Any idea what the problem might be?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you see any log on system.log, exception.log, console log?

Comment: I see `debug.log` only. The `exception.log` and `system.log` are empty

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: There is no error. I can see other payment methods only my custom method is missing. The problem is that I don't know what the problem is :)

Answer (score 0):

**For debugging why your module is not showing**

- You have to make sure your module is enabled in app/etc/config.php
- Make sure that you checked the module configuration in backend

  - Enabled?
  - Credential is full fill?
- Any error log in exception.log, system.log, console log.
- If you don't know how to use xdebug

  - Install that module on Default Magento, does it works?

**About your module I can see that the module has a problem**

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): The XML in file "/app/app/code/VUB/ECard/etc/payment.xml" is invalid:
Element 'method', attribute 'name': 'vubecard' is not a valid value of the atomic type 'xs:ID'.
Line: 10

Verify the XML and try again.

Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): The XML in file "/app/app/code/VUB/ECard/etc/payment.xml" is invalid:
Element 'method', attribute 'name': 'vubecard' is not a valid value of the atomic type 'xs:ID'.
Line: 10
```

After fix the issue I can see the module's configuration in the backend.

[image]

Comment: Where did you find this error, please? I am testing it on a fresh installation of [magento 2.4.5-p1](https://hub.docker.com/layers/bitnami/magento/2.4.5-p1/images/sha256-dfdf5176cde274e68752e48e4344ffec0a702b8bb4091174c594380392a91444?context=explore) with developer mode enabled. When I install the module, I see it in admin and I can save the config. When I go to the checkout, the module is not there. `exception.log` is empty (does not exist in log).

Comment: Just goes to the admin you will see the error.

Comment: Many thanks, I had to restart my docker. I fixed the module name, but the problem is, that I still don't see the payment method in checkout. Would you mind helping me with the issue?

Comment: You can chat with me on Skype: hieu_hidro